# Logstash aggregate filter and Elasticsearch output plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, pipeline

Firstly I wanna say that I am new to ElasticSearch, Logstash and ELK stack.
I'm trying to pull data from MySQL to ElasticSearch to support full-text search. There are many relations in MySQL (one to many, many to many) and I want to make them arrays in a single index in ElasticSearch. That's why my approach is to use Logstash aggregate filter plugin with JDBC driver.

Here is how my pipeline looks like:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/jdbc_driver/mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://db:3306/my_db"
        jdbc_user => "username"
        jdbc_password => "password"
        jdbc_paging_enabled => true
        tracking_column => "last_update"
        tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
        use_column_value => true
        schedule => "*/1 * * * *"
        jdbc_paging_mode => "explicit"
        jdbc_page_size => 1
        statement => "SELECT * FROM my_complex_view"
    }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    copy => { "id" => "[@metadata][_id]"}
    remove_field => ["@version", "@timestamp"]
  }
  aggregate {
              task_id => "%{id}"
              code => "
              map['id'] = event.get('id'),
              map['biid'] = event.get('biid'),
              map['name'] = event.get('name'),
              map['items'] ||= []
              map['items'] << {
                   'id' => event.get('item_id'),
                   'created_at' => event.get('item_created_at'),
                   'office_id' => event.get('item_office_id'),
                   'parent_id' => event.get('item_parent_id'),
                   'setting_id' => event.get('item_setting_id'),
              }
              event.cancel()
              "
              push_previous_map_as_event => true
              timeout => 5
     }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
    index => "my_index"
    ilm_enabled => false
    ssl => false
    document_id => "%{id}"
  }
}
```

However, when I run the pipeline and look at the logs from logstash, it calls to ElasticSearch bulk API with `index` action and the `_id` is the whole aggregated event map:

```
{
"index":{"id, field1, field2, items[]"},
"_index":"my_index",
"routing":null
}
```

So ElasticSearch returns the error with reason `mapper[id] can not be changed from type [long] to [text]`.
Does anyone have any idea of my problem?

Thank you in advance.